# XSL built email stripping Outlook conditional statement

Tags: xml, email, outlook, xslt-2.0

I'm having trouble rendering the outlook conditional statements used to sit two tables next to eachother and then stack on smaller screens. For some reason when the email is built.

For the section it's need in, I currently have (I'm aware this needs cleaning up):-

```
<table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth" bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:10px; color:#000000; font-size:14px; letter-spacing:1px; text-transform: uppercase; padding:5px;">Order Number: <xsl:value-of select="StrongMail/ordernumber" /></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="center" style="padding:0">
    <xsl:for-each select="StrongMail/productlineitems/line">
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <td align="center">
    <![endif]-->
    <table width="289" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="deviceWidth" style="width:50%; padding:5px; margin:5px 0 5px 0;">
      <tr>
       <td align="left">
           <img width="68" border="0" style="width: 68px; vertical-align:bottom;" >
                <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select='imageURL' /></xsl:attribute>            
            </img>
          </td>
          <td align="left">
            <table style="padding:0 5px 0 5px;">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:10px; font-size:12px;"><xsl:value-of select="desc" /></p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:10px; font-size:12px;">QUANTITY : <xsl:value-of select="quantity"/></p>
                </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
     <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      </td>
      <![endif]-->
    </xsl:for-each>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: Well, comments in your XSLT code are not output in the result tree, you need to use the `xsl:comment` element to create a comment in the result tree.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding xsl:comment you will also need to convert the '<' and '>' symbols to HTML names or numbers and remove the existing comment tags.

E.G.

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<td align="center">
<![endif]-->
```

Would become...

```
<xsl:comment>[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]&gt;
&lt;td align="center"&gt;
&lt;![endif]</xsl:comment>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the above doesn't work then you can try the below code. I used to work for a company that used StrongView and XSL.

`<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>`

It will take a while but if you are using find and replace (i prefer notepad ++ for this) then it will be easy.

An example of a commented out HTML block will look like below:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>td align="center"<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>![endif]<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
```

Let me know if this works for you.